# Loopback ACLS principalId/type for IBM Bluemix Mobile Client Access?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, loopbackjs, strongloop, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to protect my loopback app Models so that users authenticated via the Mobile Client Access ([bluemix](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-mca-token-validation-strategy)) can only POST(1) to a single model and the rest is accessible for authenticated users/roles (via User/Role) only.

I'd like to use model.json acls for this (since I don't know any better). But I can find no reference to the principalId/type of the Mobile Client Access user/strategy. What am I missing?

(1) Using this helper.js https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/651#issuecomment-167111395 to achieve this.

Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used a `model.json` acls before, but here's how I protected specific endpoints in my simple LoopBack application:

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/mobiledashboard-storecatalog-backend

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question, or if you would like me to see if I can find a `model.json` acls solution for you.